# Vector find function working in Visual Studio but not in GCC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, g++

I have a function that does what I want it to do in Visual Studio, and I was transferring it to GCC to make sure everything worked there.

I now have a plethora of compilation errors stemming from my use of the `std::find` function.

I was hoping someone could take a look and help me figure out why I am only getting these errors in GCC. Here is a sample of the code: http://cpp.sh/6pky

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   vector < list < pair <string, string> > > v;
   v.resize(15);
   pair<string, string> k ("foo", "bar");
   auto & whichList = v[2];
   if(find(begin(whichList), end(whichList), k) != end(whichList))
       cout << "true";

}
```

The part in question is `find(begin(whichList), end(whichList), k)`.

I am getting an error that says I cannot compare a list of pairs with a pair (an issue I have been dealing a lot with this week) which I understand. I'm mostly curious as to why VS2015 not only doesn't recognize this error, but also performs the task appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You didn't `#include <algorithm>`**, [the header in which `std::find` lives](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

[When I add it, your code compiles in GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c165b1d84a76e296).

Visual Studio's standard library implementation, purely by chance, must be organised such that the headers you *did* `#include` happen to themselves end up `#include`ing `<algorithm>`.

[Always include the correct headers for the types and functions that you use.](http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/tomalaks-tuesday-tip-6-an-inclusion-pitfall/)